# 2005 Civic - Strange electrical issues

Tags: electrical, battery, civic

My wife's 05 civic started to have some strange electrical issues. I'm not sure even where to start troubleshooting.

She originally complained that both headlights died simultaneously. I assumed that one was already dead and she only noticed when the second went out. There were no issues with the brights and the fuses were fine.

Then things got stranger ... the SRS light started coming on at random intervals while driving, stay on for a period of time and then go off. Now the battery light started doing the same.

The battery itself seems to have plenty of power and it's relatively new (7 months).

Thinking back, the civic has been through a lot more headlights and batteries than my Accord (01). I've replaced the battery three times in the last four years and the headlights at least once a year.

It could be the battery, alternator, computer or ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "battery" light usually indicates an alternator fault. Do have it checked.

Answer (score 3):

The regulator in your alternator could be faulty.  If it is allowing the alternator to produce too high a voltage, this could cause early failure of you bulbs and your battery.

With the engine running you can use a voltmeter to check the voltage at the battery, it should be between 13.8 and 14.4 volts.  If it is above 14.4 volts, then you have found your fault.

If you have an OBD2 reader, you will be able to read the battery voltage using that.